# Java - BungeeCord shutdown

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit, bungeecord

I tried to shutdown my BungeeCord-/Proxy-Server using a plugin. But I can't find something like `Bukkit.shutdown();` or `Bukkit.dispatchCommand();`, which can be used to stop a Bukkit-/Spigot-Server.

Sorry for my bad English and thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To stop a Bungeecord server, you should call [`ProxyServer.getInstance().stop()`](http://ci.md-5.net/job/BungeeCord/ws/api/target/apidocs/net/md_5/bungee/api/ProxyServer.html#stop()).

Comment: Thank you very much :) I did not saw these method.

Comment: To be fair, I also had a hard time finding this method in the documentation, :)